# Проблема с фильтрами в категории Cs-cart

Tags: cs-cart

Обнаружилась проблема с фильтрами, в левой колонке при выборе ползунка цена не меняется, при выборе параметров - чекбоксов, checked не срабатывает, хотя сами фильтры работают, но изменения видны только после перезагрузки страницы.

Подскажите пожалуйста с чем это может быть связано?

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена!
Долго искал, а оказалось что фильтры между собой конфликтовали из-за дублирующий id'шников!